# QMetry : com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.ScenarioFactory.getTestsFromFile() threw an exception

Tags: qaf

Getting exception when tried to run suite bdd file. also the same code does work in one of my fried machine. I have also installed TestNG and BDD plugin.

```
The factory method class com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.ScenarioFactory.getTestsFromFile() threw an exception
    at org.testng.internal.FactoryMethod.invoke(FactoryMethod.java:197)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processFactory(TestNGClassFinder.java:223)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processMethod(TestNGClassFinder.java:179)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processClass(TestNGClassFinder.java:171)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:121)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:370)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:192)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1271)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1107)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.FactoryMethod.invoke(FactoryMethod.java:167)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Can you share bdd file? Look like it is not in proper format.

Comment: @Swapnil, please provide detailed information including your configuration and other related code.